# How not to delete a child object when parent is deleted?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have this class

```
class Vote {    
    Post post
}
```

When I delete an object of `Vote` it should not cascade delete `Post`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are asking about Grails, not groovy. 
If yes, then in order to leave the Post instance in the DB, you need to remove `static belongsTo = [ vote:Vote ]` from the Post class

P.S. it's good to provide a bit more information on your problem, so we don't have to play guess-game here...